# Adding Column widget in ModalBottomSheet showing Transparent View- Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, android-bottomsheetdialog, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I have to show ModalBottomSheet with this widget : **showModalBottomSheet**

For that  I set all the required properties of ModalBottomSheet and as a builder part I am doing it as below :

```
builder: (_) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text("Sample "),
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return NagarTiming();
              }),
        ],
      );
    }
```

You can see that There is a **Text** widget inside **Column** widget which I have used there to consider it as a Title of my ModalBottomSheet.

But unfortunately, when I execute or call **showModalBottomSheet** method, Its showing me just transparent window or view.

Note that without **Column** widget and **Text** widget If I return only ListView as builder for ModalBottomSheet, **Its working fine for me.**

What might be the issue in showing Title (Text in Column widget) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the issue with the vertical size. ListView inside Column widget should have height concern. So used Flexible widget as below :

```
builder: (_) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text("Sample "),
          Flexible(
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return NagarTiming();
              }),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your `ListView` with `Expanded` inside Column in order to get available height. Else, it will raise unbounded height issue. To set background color you can use `backgroundColor` from `showModalBottomSheet`.

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
    builder: (_) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          Text("Sample "),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
```

You can check [Unbounded height / width | Decoding Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jckqXR5CrPI&vl=en) and [ShrinkWrap vs slivers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUqDNnv_dh0)

Answer (score 1):

add shrinkWrap:true parameter to ListView widget and mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.min to your Column widget
It should work fine

Answer (score 0):

Wrap with sizedbox and assign width double.infinity

```
builder: (_) {
  return SizedBox(
       width:double.infinity 
      child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("Sample "),
      ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return NagarTiming();
          }),
    ],
   )
  );
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).